# Error: failed to download "install/kubernetes/helm/istio

Tags: shell, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio, istio-kiali

I created a cluster on the Google cloud platform.
I got below error while executing the helm command. What is wrong here?

```
curl -L https://git.io/getLatestIstio | ISTIO_VERSION=1.2.2 sh -


helm template istio install/kubernetes/helm/istio 
--set global.mtls.enabled=false --set racing.enabled=true 
--set kiali.enabled=true --set grafana.enabled=true 
--namespace istio-system > istio.yaml
```

> Error: template:
> istio/charts/gateways/templates/rolebindings.yaml:4:7: executing
> "istio/charts/gateways/templates/rolebindings.yaml" at  <($spec.sds)
> and (eq $spec.sds.enabled true)>: can't give argument to non-function
> $spec.sds

> Use --debug flag to render out invalid YAML

Comment: Can you post what's in line 4 of `istio/charts/gateways/templates/rolebindings.yaml`?

Comment: Yes. error message:template: istio/charts/gateways/templates/rolebindings.yaml:4:7: executing "istio/charts/gateways/templates/rolebindings.yaml" at 
<($spec.sds) and (eq $spec.sds.enabled true)>: can't give argument to non-function $spec.sds

Comment: It is written somewhere to do as follows, but I do not know how to do it.  follow the below steps.

In files,
`/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/charts/gateways/templates/rolebindings.yaml
/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/charts/gateways/templates/role.yaml

replace below line

{‌{- if ($spec.sds) and (eq $spec.sds.enabled true) }}

with

{‌{- if and ($spec.sds) (eq $spec.sds.enabled true) }} `  @Rico

Comment: looks like you are missing a variable somewhere

Comment: I implemented all the command lines in the tutorial one by one. Could it be version related? How else can I do? @Rico

Comment: is `spec.sds` defined in your `values.yaml`?

Comment: `ISTIO_VERSION=1.2.2`. Istio *1.2.2* is very old, and very unsupported. Do you get the same error when trying to install newer version (preferably latest *1.13.2*)?

Comment: I don't know. I ran it from google cloud shell.I just started learning Kubernetes.I may not understand what you are saying.

Comment: Either remove `| ISTIO_VERSION=1.2.2` from `curl` command, or replace it with `| ISTIO_VERSION=1.13.2`, and then try to install istio again. Or, even better, use [official Istio docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/helm/) for installation instructions

Comment: I tried ISTIO_VERSION=1.13.2 and failed. I will look at the official page.Thanks @p10l